# Transform Sequence Summary data to Long and Wide format

Tags: r, casting, sequence, dplyr, rep

I need to transform some data that come in the form of a summary. 
First into long format and then into wide format.

For each id, we have the number of times an id performed an activity. 
The data are ordered.

For example, for id 1, he performed 3 times "a" first, then 4 times "c", and so on.

```
data = rbind(
  c(1, 'a', 3, 1), 
  c(1, 'c', 4, 2), 
  c(1, 'b', 6, 3), 
  c(2, 'a', 2, 1), 
  c(2, 'c', 1, 2), 
  c(2, 'a', 5, 3) 
  )
data = as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data) = c('id', 'act', 'times', 'order')

  id act times order
  1   a     3     1
  1   a     4     2
  1   b     6     3
  2   a     2     1
  2   c     1     2
  2   a     5     3
```

First, I need to transform this dataset into a long format. For each id, I need to repeat the activity (ordered), the number of times it has been done.

```
  id act
  1  a
  1  a
  1  a
  ...
  1  b
  2  a
  2  a
  2  c
  2  a
  ...
```

I am using something like

```
as.data.frame( cbind( as.character( rep(data$id, data$times)), as.character( rep(data$act, data$times))) )
```

but it is so cumbersome.

My first question is: do you have a solution for simplifying this transformation ?

Then once the data have been transformed into this long format, 
I need to transform it again to a wide format in order to get something like

```
 id  act_time1 act_time2 act_time3 act_time... act_timeN
 "1" "a"       "a"       "a"       "..."       "b"      
 "2" "a"       "a"       "c"       "..."       "a"
```

Apparently, I am not using cast correctly here

```
cast(dataLong, formula = V1 ~ V2, value.var = 'V2')
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: You can do `library(splitstackshape) ; expandRows(data, "times")` for the first part of the question, though I'm not sure I understand your desired output in the second part of the question. For example, there is no `b` when `id == 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second part is just a simple transformation from long to wide, but maybe I did not reproduce perfectly the cases.

Comment: May be `library(splitstackshape);library(reshape2);dcast(getanID(expandRows(data, 'times'), c('act', 'id'))[, indx:= paste0(order, .id)], id~indx, value.var='act')`

Comment: Maybe `library(data.table) ; dcast(setDT(expandRows(data, "times"))[, indx := seq_len(.N), by = id], id ~ indx, value.var = "act")`